# Purge temporary tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

When I query for the tables in my *tempdb* I get a long list and some of  them are more than 6 months old. I would like to remove them, but when I try I get the message

> Cannot drop the table '#A0033175', because it does not exist or you do
>   not have permission.

I guess it is because this table belongs to other users, even the SA user can't drop it. Is there any way to have those old table dropped? I would have thought they had to be removed when their sessions were over.

SQL Server 2012 (SP3)

Comment: Restart SQL server should drop them. But they should be automatically dropped when the user session disconnects. Which would seem to mean there are still user sessions over 6 months old? But those tables with AXXXXXXX I believe are used internally to SQL so they will probably be recreated often.

Comment: It is very odd. I have about 200 tables which are there since last December. They even show up in the Temporary tables of TEMPDB in SSMS.

Comment: `some of them are more than 6 months old `#temp table will be dropped when session closes.so how come you have a session which is active for 6 months

Comment: Are there old sessions on your server? Check for them using sys.dm_exec_sessions filtering order by login_time

Comment: @sepupic - thank you and yes, some sessions are that old and they are not user sessions. Probably SQL server creates them for some reason on start!

Comment: Try DBCC INPUTBUFFER (session number) to see what that sessions executed

Answer (score 1):

The table name is actually something like #abc_____012345 where everything except for the initial characters following the 'abc'name portion is added by SQL Server to make the table unique to the session that created it. This way the proc can be run in multiple sessions (windows) and the temporary tables don't step on each other.

To get rid of these temp tables make sure the sessions are closed. Typically someone may have gone home without shutting SSMS leaving a bunch of Windows open that created the temp tables. Killing the sessions will cause SQL Server to drop the temp tables. You may have a very long running query (probably some kind of problem) that has been running for months and therefore the temp tables it created are still around. Be careful about killing sessions - you can make yourself very unpopular if you kill the 'wrong' session.

This applies to table with a single # sign in front of the name. Double ## signs signify  a table that is visible from all sessions and SQL Server does not change the name to make the table name unique.